# Delete data from tables php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables which i want to `update` at the same time `via 1 query` if possible. I have a `customer table` with a `primary key of cusomerid` which is set to auto increment and a `complaints table` where `customerid` is set to a `foreign key.`

I want to delete from the customer table and put simply when i delete that customerid it should also delete from the complaints table. Hope this makes sense.Can anyone explain how to achieve my above 2 goal?

```
    <?php
include("functions.inc.php");
display_header("Delete a record");
?>
<?php
require_once("dbconnect.inc.php");
?>
<!--displays array easier to read-->
<?php //echo '<pre>';?>  

<div id="container">

<header><?php include("header.inc.php");?></header>

<nav><?php include("navbar.inc.php");?></nav>

<?php include("sidebar.inc.php");?>

<p>
    <img src="images/relationsimage.PNG"/>


    <form action="delete.php" method="post"> 
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$resultset = $conn->query($query);
while ($row = $resultset->fetch())
{
 echo "<p>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='customer[]' id='customer".$row['customerid']."' value='".$row['customerid']."'>";
echo "<label for='customer".$row['customerid']."'>".$row['title']." ".$row['forename']." ".$row['surname']." ".$row['roadname']." ".$row['town']." ".$row['county']." ".$row['postcode']." ".$row['phonenumber']." ".$row['paymentmethod']."</label>";
echo "</p>";
}
?>


<input type="submit" value="delete these sales leads">

</form>
 <?php   

    if (!isset($_POST['customer']))
{

   echo "";
   exit;
}


    $query="DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerid=:customerid";
    $pr_stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
$affected_rows=0;
foreach($_POST['customer'] as $cusid)
{
    $pr_stmt->bindValue(':customerid',$cusid);
    $affected_rows += $pr_stmt->execute();  
}
echo "Deleted ".$affected_rows." customer from customers table";
$conn=NULL; //close the connection
?>
</p>


<footer><?php include("footer.inc.php");?></footer> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it does. But where is your question? Where is the part of you explaining what you already tried? Hint: When setting the foreign key, you can define what happens `ON DELETE`

Comment: you need to add a foreign key constraint to delete from the complaints table when you delete from the customer table using something like ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Here is what i have so far but i need to include the complaints table in here somehow aswell, as i said i am really new to this so all help is massively appreciated.

Comment: just added my code above to show what ive done so far,

Comment: If your question is that you want to delete the entry in complaint table for the customer id,delete the entry in customer table for the same customer id, you can simply achieve this by creating a rule in customer table.

Comment: Could u add more AdRock, really new to this so the simplest things can be tricky lol

Comment: do you know how to create table and insert data?. i think you have to learn from beginning..

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to have your foreign key have an on delete property set, see this tutorial, it will show you how to set up the on delete so that the row in the corresponding table is also deleted: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/